# Batch file to Play VLC movie after Windows 7 wakes

Tags: windows, batch-file, vlc, wakeup

I've a task that run a batch file to sleep the computer and I have another task that runs a batch to play a video (and wake up the pc)

I'm using this basic code (wake up script):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --loop --fullscreen "C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\STARTUP_VIDEO\list.xspf"
```

If I click in this batch file the VLC starts playing. But if I create a task to wake up the computer with this batch file, the computer wakes but nothing happens!
Any help?

Comment: Did you correctly set the task? And another solution is to use the `shell:startup` folder to call this file. Using the `start` command might make parameters work (or not, roll the dice)

Comment: what is the first thing you see after computer wake have you tired putting `pause` statement before and after above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(folder) startup 
something before that code of vlc

This works for me, but I do not know if it's perfect.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto movie

:movie  
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --loop --fullscreen "D:\video.mp4"

workt 
oke  C:\Users\gg\Desktop\eee.xspf
```

Then continue with the rest of your code.